# Should TimeWindows be the same when joining two KTable dervied from TimeWindows

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I use two different retention time for two different KTable, and it works with RocksDB States and changelog Kafka Topics.

KTable is generated from KStream and `groupBy` and then `windowedBy`.

I believe when joining `KStream` with windowing, `TimeWindows` is the same. I'm wondering will there be benefit or drawback if `TimeWindows` parameters are different, when joining two different KTable windowed by `TimeWindows`?

code snippet:

```java
final KStream<Integer, String> eventStream = builder.stream("events",
                        Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.String())
                                .withOffsetResetPolicy(Topology.AutoOffsetReset.EARLIEST));

final KTable<Windowed<Integer>, String> eventWindowTable = eventStream.groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(60)).until(Duration.ofSeconds(100).toMillis()))
                .reduce((oldValue, newValue) -> newValue);

final KStream<Integer, String> clickStream = builder.stream("clicks",
                Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.String())
                        .withOffsetResetPolicy(Topology.AutoOffsetReset.EARLIEST));

final KTable<Windowed<Integer>, String> clickWindowTable = clickStream.groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).until(Duration.ofSeconds(70).toMillis()))
                .reduce((oldValue, newValue) -> newValue);

final KTable<Windowed<Integer>, String> join = eventWindowTable.leftJoin(clickWindowTable,
                (event, click) -> event + " ; " + click + " ; " + Instant.now()
        );
```

Initially I thought joining two different KTable with different `TimeWindows` parameters will not work because the joining relies on TimeWindowedKey, a key for the time slot. But after testing, it works as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join is executed because the *type* of both keys is the same: `Windowed<Integer>`. The join will of course only produce a result if the keys are the same. Assume you have the following windows (note that only the window start timestamp is stored for `TimeWindows`):

```
eventWindowTable: <A,0>        <A,60>       

clickWindowTable: <A,0> <A,30> <A,60> <A,90>
```

For this case, only `<A,0>` and `<A,60>` would join. Hence, having different windows, does impact your result, because the window start timestamp is part of the key and some windows will never join (eg, `<A,30>` and `<A,90>` in our example).